# Litespeed Product Update Interval - Do nothing (deactivate)

Tags: php

Is there a way to deactivate Litespeed Product Update Interval? because we run a nightly cache purge at 4am. This is done to get the highest cache hit rate in Cloudflare. We would get a higher cache hit rate if Litespeed Product Update Interval is deactivated.

The website would be crawled right after the purge all.

To get a website fully cached through the day.